# Does openstreetmapx.jl offer yen_k_shortest_paths?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

Graph.jl has shortest path algorithms implementations of `dijkstra_shortest_paths, floyd_warshall_shortest_paths, bellman_ford_shortest_paths` and `yen_k_shortest_paths`.

I've seen in the source code of openstreetmapx.jl that it uses  `dijkstra_shortest_paths` or `bellman_ford_shortest_paths` but didn't see any instruction of how to directly call them on a `map` object.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to connect map to a graph and then call available shortest rout algorithem? Or is there any direct call inside osmx?

I'm particularly looking for `yen_k_shortest_paths`  to call in on a Toronto map.  Something similar to: `OpenStreetMapX.yen_k_shortest_paths(map, source, end)`
Is there any function capable of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a yen method implementation in Graphs.jl and you can use it

Let's load the demo data:

```
using OpenStreetMapX, Graphs
 mx = get_map_data(joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm") , use_cache=false, trim_to_connected_graph=true);
```

And now you can do to find 3 shortest routes between nodes 2975020212 and 140345752:

```
julia> paths = Graphs.yen_k_shortest_paths(mx.g, mx.v[2975020212], mx.v[140345752], mx.w, 3)
Graphs.YenState{Float64, Int64}([2275.1221685482883, 2314.3738183345918, 2353.253695410896], [[1740, 1704, 2  …   1163, 982, 422], [1740, 1704, 2  …  1163, 982, 422], [1740, 1704, 2 …  1163, 982, 422]])
```

Than you can get back node ids:

```
julia> [getindex.(Ref(mx.n), path) for path in paths.paths]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [2975020212, 2975020214, 2975020216  …  2549289586, 140345751, 140345752]
 [2975020212, 2975020214, 2975020216  …  2549289586, 140345751, 140345752]
 [2975020212, 2975020214, 2975020216  …  2549289586, 140345751, 140345752]
```

Comment: can you give me some help here please @Przemyslaw Szufel? I've testing different maps and different nodes and calling `yen_k`. It seems that whenever you load a real osm map, the `Graphs.yen_k_shortest_paths` always return K copy of the same path, and not K distinct path.  This is not the case for a non osm graph. Even in you example if you see all three path are the same. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: This is not true. The code in my example loads a real osm map and each path is different. You can even see that the first path has lenght of 2275, the second 2314 and the third 2353. And they consists of different nodes.

Comment: To be more precise in my example `length.(paths.paths)'` yields  `30  34  26` so each path has even a different number of nodes.